# custom tableviewCells for UITableView created programatically in storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my app I am using storyboard. But I created a `UITableView` programmatically instead of dragging from Object Library. And now I want to customize the cells of that programmatically created `UITableView`. Can anyone help me by providing an example of creating a `UITableViewCell` programmatically in storyboard?

Answer (score 8):

I'd avoid putting layout and building of your cell into `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

To create a custom cell programatically you should first create a `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Add to it the `labels`, `imageViews`, etc... Add the as subViews of the `cell.contentView`.

**PROGRAMATICALLY**

i.e.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 21)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_label];
    }
    return self;
}
```

If you want to do layout stuff of the cell then in the `MyCell` class you can do...

```
- (void)layoutSubViews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // layout stuff relative to the size of the cell.
}
```

Then in the `tableViewController` you need to register the cell class...

In `viewDidLoad`...

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
```

**WITH INTERFACE BUILDER**

Still create the custom subclass but also create a xib file of the same name. Then in your xib file you can hook up the outlets instead of having to create them in the init of the cell. (If you do it this way then the init will not be called anyway).

The only other change you need is that in `viewDidLoad` you need to register the nib for the cell not the class.

Like this...

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
```

Then everything else works the same.

**USING THE CELL**

To use the cell that you have created the subclass for...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];

    [self configureCustomCell:(MyCell*)cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCustomCell:(MyCell*)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // do all you logic of getting any info from arrays etc in here.

    cell.label.text = @"Blah".
}
```

**SUMMARY**

Doing it this way means that your tableviewcontroller is only interested in putting stuff into the cells. If you put all your logic for building your cells as well everything just gets really messy.

It also means you don't have to deal with loads of different tags to save and retrieve different UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'll describe two options: Adding the cell by using Interface Builder (simpler), and adding the cell programmatically:

**By using Interface Builder**

Once you have created the cell in Interface Builder and added subviews with your custom content, open the Attributes inspector, select the *Custom* style and enter a unique identifier in the *Reuse identifier* text field (for example, "anIdentifier"). Next, select the cell fields that you want to access programmatically and set a unique *tag* number for each one of them (it's under the *View* section).

Then, in your data source code, implement this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"anIdentifier"];

    UILabel *label;

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1]; // Set a constant for this so your fellow developers understand this number
    label.text = @"This is a test";

    return cell;
}
```

**Programmatically**

If you want to create the cell programmatically, then the code should be something similar to this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"anIdentifier";

    UILabel *aLabel;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]];

        aLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...]];
        aLabel.tag = 1; // Set a constant for this
        aLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        aLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        aLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        aLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];
    } else {
        aLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    }

    aLabel.text = @"This is a test";

    return cell;
}
```

There's more information at Apple's website: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Comment: UITextAlignment... is deprecated. You should use NSTextAlignment... instead. Wow, I just read those Apple docs. Are they really telling you to put EVERYTHING into one place!? It makes things so much messier and more complicated. What if you want to use the same cell in a different place? You copy past all that code? LOL!

Comment: Starting with iOS 6 `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will not return `nil` anymore. You get a new or reused cell automatically. If that's your minimum deployment target, you can leave the `if`/`else` construct out.

Comment: Daniel, that's only the case if you have a class (or nib) registered for the reuse identifier as per my answer. If you don't have a class registered then a nil cell will be returned.

Comment: I would put the cells in sepearate XIB files and load them on demand. That way you don't have to layout them in code and still can reuse them easily in different places.

Comment: @Fogmeister: Indeed. Good point.

Comment: @Fogmeister: I imagined that was your intention. I would just clarify a bit more by putting that "with interface builder, create a new XIB file" in there. Otherwise readers might be confused about how to put a standalone table cell in a storyboard.

Comment: You don't need a nib though. You can do it code-wise. I will edit to clear it up though. Thanks.