# i have issue with prototype table view cell that my cell text is overlapping every time when it get used

Tags: iphone, xcode

This is my code every time when i scroll my labels text are getting overleaped.Text are overlapping and i think this is because reuse of cell.
I am using storyboard and this is not a custom cell.
Need some help,every single help would be appreciated.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 static NSString *TableViewCEll =@"TableViewCell";
 UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableViewCEll forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (Cell == nil) {

    Cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableViewCEll];
}
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
imageView.frame =CGRectMake(5, 5, 100,110);
[Cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

NSArray * array =[[self.ListOfCarArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"CarImage"];

if (array.count >0) {

    NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@uploads/Car/%@",[self.GetUserConfiDict objectForKey:@"server"],[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"name"]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc]init];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:str
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

             imageView.image = responseObject;
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Failed with error %@.",[error localizedFailureReason]);
         }];

}

UILabel * ModelLbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 10, 120, 25)];
ModelLbl.textColor       = [UIColor whiteColor];
NSDictionary *str  = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
str =[[self.ListOfCarArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Car"];
ModelLbl.text = [str objectForKey:@"model"];
[Cell.contentView addSubview:ModelLbl];


int x = 120;
int y = 50;
for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++) {

    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 84,15)];
    label.textColor       = [UIColor whiteColor];

    if (i ==1) {

        id null = [str objectForKey:@"year"];
        if ([null isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            label.text =@"";
        }
        else{
            label.text = [str objectForKey:@"year"];
            [Cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        }
    }
    else if (i == 2){

        id null = [str objectForKey:@"color"];
        if ([null isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            label.text =@"";
        }
        else{
            label.text =[str objectForKey:@"color"];
            [Cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        }
    }
    else if (i == 3){

        id null = [str objectForKey:@"price"];
        if ([null isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            label.text =@"";
        }
        else{
            label.text =[str objectForKey:@"price"];
            [Cell.contentView addSubview:label];
            x+=100;
            y = 30;
        }
    }
    else if (i ==4) {

        id null = [str objectForKey:@"miles"];
        if ([null isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            label.text =@"";
        }
        else{
            label.text =[str objectForKey:@"miles"];
            [Cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        }
    }
    else if (i == 5){

        id null = [str objectForKey:@"stock_number"];
        if ([null isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            label.text =@"";
        }
        else{
            label.text =[str objectForKey:@"stock_number"];
            [Cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        }
    }
    y+=20;
}

return Cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got my answer and this is what i was searching for..

```
for (UILabel *lbl in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    if ([lbl isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        [lbl removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is caused by the reuse of the table view cell. It is not only the labels but also the imageView. You are adding the `imageView` with this method

```
[Cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

every time, while it should only be done when the cell is created, i.e. inside the

```
if (Cell == nil) {
    Cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableViewCEll];
}
```

I'd advise to use a [custom UITableViewCell subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517692/custom-tableviewcells-for-uitableview-created-programatically-in-storyboard), but if you stick with the current approach, I'd do it this way:

```
static int IMAGE_VIEW_TAG = 1;
if (Cell == nil) {
    Cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableViewCEll];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 100,110);
    imageView.tag = IMAGE_VIEW_TAG;
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Further below, you can refer to the imageView by the tag:

```
((UIImageView *)[Cell.contentView viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_TAG]).image = responseObject;
```

You'll have to do the same for the labels.